# How to override a target-specific variable from the command-line?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Given a makefile, with a `target-specific` defintion:***

```make
# A target-specific definition for both: 'all' and 'x'.
all : foo += target
x   : foo += target


all : x ;

x ::
    @echo '$(foo)'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
# override Makefile-level variables, with a command-line definition.
$ make foo=cmd
cmd
```

***Now, the same makefile, as above, but with a `pattern-specific` defintion:***

```make
# A pattern-specific definition that matches both targets: 'all' and 'x'.
% : foo += target


all : x ;

x ::
    @echo '$(foo)'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
# override Makefile-level variables, with a command-line definition.
$ make foo=cmd
cmd cmd cmd
```

Now, both makefiles are almost **identical**, except that:

- For ***version 1 of Makefile:*** (With *target*-specific definition), we had:
  `all : foo += target`

  `x   : foo += target`
- For ***version 2 of Makefile*** (With *pattern*-specific definition), we had:
  `%   : foo += target`

In both cases, we had basically the **same** configuration:

1. A pattern/target definition that **appends** to a previous value.
2. The pattern/target definition applies **both** to `all` and `x` targets.
3. We had a command-line definition that is suppose to *override* the makefile-level definition.

Now, interpreting or implementing that **override**, Make uses a very different methodology, for version **1** (target definition) than version **2** (pattern definition).

Let's see:

- For target definition, Make **completely ignores ANY** value defined in the makefile. Hence, the final value is: `cmd`.
- For pattern definition, however, Make comes up with "conciliatory" approach, trying to satisfy **both**, the makefile-level definition and the command-line defintion, so it:

  1. Accepts that the final value is `cmd`, per the command-line that overrides the makefile definition.
  2. But, because the makefile implies that the "patterns" are supposed to "append" additional values - never mind that those same values had been overridden - Make will still "obey" those appends, but it will done with **different** values (i.e. the "winning" command-line value), thereby reaching a "compromise" where nor does the makefile, or the command-line have sole control over the final value of the variable.

Well, these different approaches that Make takes to implement a command-line *override*, (per pattern vs target specific variables), is even more obvious when we expect the very different final results we get for them, respectively:

1. `cmd` (for target-specific).
2. `cmd cmd cmd` (for pattern-specific).

Is this justified? And how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a minimal complete example:

```
%: foo += targ

x:
    @echo $(foo)
```

Invoked as `make foo=cmd` (using GNUMake v3.81), this produces

```
cmd cmd
```

**This looks like a bug to me.** According to [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

> Variables provided on the command line (and in the environment if the
>   ‘-e’ option is in force) will take precedence [over target-specific variables].

So the += statement should have no effect. But apparently if the assignment is in a pattern rule, the command-line value overrules the *value* which the rule tries to append, but not the *act of appending it*, so that Make appends `$(foo)` to itself.